What have I cut into in my apartment? Because this doesn't look like the drywall I was expecting to find
There is a leak that caused staining and rot in one particular spot in my wall. I was going to open it up, patch, and then put drywall back. Instead, I find what seems like cement that melted to sand and it spilled out of the wall as I was cutting. There is a hole where I see the leak exactly and need to fix it. But what in the world is this substrate I cut into because I don't think it's drywall and I'm not sure how to proceed with patching the wall back as planned.



That’s probably plaster and lath. So fix the plumbing (or have your landlord fix it as appropriate — not sure where you’re located), and then you need backing behind and a bunch of plaster or drywall or both.

This apartment is old as hell and I'm pretty sure the involvement at this point to do this wall justice is to tear the whole thing down and replace. The landlord/super aren't that type so I think the best course of action is to seal off the leak, put the new drywall in, seal it up, paint it the same color, and call it a day.

keep all of your receipts and deduct the costs from your rental

If you feel you are on you own with the repair, although it really is the responsibility of the landlord to do repairs.
That said, it does look like you have a newer version of lath and plaster as Aloysius commented. The newer version is "rock lath", that is the white layer under the crumbly sand. The crumbly sand is the brown coat wihich has had its portland leached out for the long time the leak has been going on. Not 100% positive, just an educated guess.
It can be repaired with regular drywall. When cutting the wall material to gain access for the repair, whether you or the plumber does it, take it back to the point where all the material is sound. Then wood backer can be screwed on the inside of the wall to the rock lath, driving the screws through the plaster. The total thickness of the plaster, including the rock lath willl be about 3/4"-1" thick. 3/8" of that will be the rock lath. Stop driving the screws at that depth, any deeper and it hold will fail. The plaster will typicall crack out of the way, don't sweat that, the important thing is the rock lath stays intact.
You may find a stud to cut the plaster to the center of, that  may simplify the repair.
Once the backer is in place or the studs are found you may be able to use 2 layers of 3/8" sheetrock or 1/2? with the right thickness of shims to make the drywall flush or at the worst, slightly recessed to the original plaster. Then tape, coat, and skim your repair as may be found elsewhere on Stack Exchange.
